# How to store Cosine Similarity values individually?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cosine-similarity

I know this is a very basic question, but please forgive me. I have a python script which is calculating cosine similarity of sentences. The result the script is returning is like this: `[[0.72894156 0.96235985 0.61194754]]`. I want to store these three values into an array or list individually, so I can find the minimum and maximum values. When I store them in an array, it stores them altogether in a single value. Here is the script:

```
sentence_embeddings = model.encode(sentences)
sentence_embeddings.shape
result = (cosine_similarity(
        [sentence_embeddings[0]],
        sentence_embeddings[1:]
))
print(result)
```

Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: what do you mean by "store these three values into an array or list individually"? Can you show the desired outcome as well as what the sentence embeddings look like/shape of it so we can understand your question better?

Comment: @rcshon Like array/list should contain each value in a separate index: arr[0] = 0.72894156, arr[1] =  0.96235985, arr[2] =  0.61194754 and this is what sentence_embeddings.shape prints = (4, 768)

Comment: isn't it just `result_you_want = result[0]`?

Comment: @rcshon it returns [0.72894156 0.96235985 0.61194754] altogether.

Comment: Is that not what you wanted? If you wanted  [[0.72894156], [0.96235985], [0.61194754]], you can simply do `result.reshape(-1, 1)`. Otherwise, please clarify your requirements in the question so others can know what you want.

Comment: Or for higher dimensions you can just do a transpose: `result.T`

Comment: @rcshon The reshape command seems to work as well. Thanks for the help! This looks like a better solution.

Comment: No problem, have clarified your requirements and the solution as an answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify, OP is asking for the result `[[0.72894156, 0.96235985, 0.61194754]]` of shape `(1, 3)` to become `[[0.72894156], [0.96235985], [0.61194754]]` of shape `(3, 1)`.

As mentioned in the comments, we can either use `.reshape` or a more generalizable way of transposing `.T`.

`result.reshape(-1, 1)` and `result.T`

Answer (score 0):

This may help. I came across something similar and treated the output like an array.  To get the specific score based on the texts I compared I did the following:

```
cos_text = [TextA, TextB]
cv = CountVectorizer()
count_matrix = cv.fit_transform(cos_text)

#word matrix
doc_term_matrix = count_matrix.todense()
df_matrix = pd.DataFrame(doc_term_matrix,
                         columns=cv.get_feature_names_out())
#individual score
score=cosine_similarity(df_matrix)
cs_scoreA = score[0,1]
cs_scoreB = score[1,0]
```